# Use of Min() and Max() with MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a simple table which stores results of subject, so one user may have done few subject and they may have different marks. I want to create a stored procedure to retrieve min and max subject details for given student:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
  PROCEDURE `Search_Min_Marks_For_Student`(IN Student_code SMALLINT)
BEGIN

SELECT Subject_Subject_code AS `Minimum Scored Subject`,
       Subject_title AS `Subject Title`,
       Min(Total_mk) AS Marks 
FROM result,subject 
WHERE result.Student_Student_code = Student_code AND
      Subject_Subject_code=Subject_code;

END
```

I wrote one for minimum score and it works fine, but is there a way I can add max results to the same query?

```sql
-- Table structure for table `result`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `result`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `result` (
  `Result_code` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Student_Student_code` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `Subject_Subject_code` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `Practical_mk` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `Assignment_mk` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `Exam_mk` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `Total_mk` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `Grade` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Result_code`),
  KEY `fk_Result_Subject1_idx` (`Subject_Subject_code`),
  KEY `fk_Result_Student1_idx` (`Student_Student_code`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Result_Student1` FOREIGN KEY (`Student_Student_code`) REFERENCES `student` (`Student_code`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Result_Subject1` FOREIGN KEY (`Subject_Subject_code`) REFERENCES `subject` (`Subject_code`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

```sql
--
-- Table structure for table `subject`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `subject`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `subject` (
  `Subject_code` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Subject_title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Num_of_credits` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Course_Course_code` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `Department_Dep_code` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Subject_code`),
  KEY `fk_Subject_Course1_idx` (`Course_Course_code`),
  KEY `fk_Subject_Department1_idx` (`Department_Dep_code`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Subject_Course1` FOREIGN KEY (`Course_Course_code`) REFERENCES `course` (`Course_code`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Subject_Department1` FOREIGN KEY (`Department_Dep_code`) REFERENCES `department` (`Dep_code`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8004 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: put `max()` function in same query..

Comment: i'm not sure if your current procedure works fine because you didn't have the `GROUP BY` clause causing to give random value for `Subject_Subject_code` and `Subject_title`.

Comment: this gives me the min value and the relevant subject code. but if i do same with max() as separate procedure it pass me the max value but not the correct subject code its give the minimum subject code always.

Comment: can you post the schema for the tables as well as the sample output? most likely @JW웃 is correct in that you will need to use `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

You can get both using a (somewhat verbose) join, with their corresponding code and title. This query returns the best and worst subject as two separate rows;

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.Subject_Subject_code, s.Subject_title, r1.Total_mk
FROM result r1
LEFT JOIN result r2 
  ON r1.Total_mk > r2.Total_mk
 AND r1.Student_Student_code = r2.Student_Student_code
LEFT JOIN result r3 
  ON r1.Total_mk < r3.Total_mk
 AND r1.Student_Student_code = r3.Student_Student_code
JOIN Subject s
  ON r1.Subject_code=s.Subject_Subject_code
WHERE (r2.Total_mk IS NULL OR r3.Total_mk IS NULL)
 AND r1.Student_Student_code = 1;
```

What it does is basically select the rows where there exists no lower score (the r2 join) or there exists no better score (the r3 join) for the student, and join with subject to get the data to display.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8bfe/1).

Comment: without `GROUP BY` clause this will give you random value for `Subject_Subject_code` and `Subject_title`. right? but if you add `GROUP BY` clause, it will list all unique records for `Subject_Subject_code` and `Subject_title`

Comment: @JW웃 Yes, you're right of course. Asleep at the wheel of the brain.

Comment: I added the table structure too. the min() gives correct value but max() doesnt give correct subject code. but i wanted to use both from one query

Comment: I was trying this one for max but it return all 2 values  DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Search_Max_Marks_For_Student`(IN Student_code SMALLINT)
BEGIN

SELECT Subject_Subject_code,Max(Total_mk) AS Marks FROM result WHERE result.Student_Student_code = Student_code GROUP BY Subject_Subject_code;

Comment: @DishanM.Francis The query in the answer is not working? You can't use MIN/MAX in that way, they will only calculate MIN/MAX on a value, not find the row where the value is the largest/smallest.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson, the way im trying is provide student code and for that student may have different results on result table and from that values i need to list minimum subject marks and maximum marks for that given user.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson, i'm sorry i'm new for stored procedures still, on the above query it gives maximum and minimum of entire table but i'm trying to get max and min for given student so for given studnet may be have 5 results so i need to find min and max out form that 5 not for entire result table. greatly appreciate your input.

Comment: @DishanM.Francis It gives the max and min for the student with code=1, see the last line in the `where`.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson you awesome it did work, one more question is there way i can add some wording saying this is the min and this is max , just curious

Comment: Thanks for every one helping me on this it was great experience.